# Layout dead end - Table cells keep overflowing

Tags: html, css

I've gotten a bit stuck with a layout I had been working on, whatever I do I cannot get the html css to react the way I need it to. I've drawn up a sketch using a screenshot:

I would like the table to fit the browser height and the bellow table cells to have its contents showing by scrolling but I cannot find the correct way to do this after googling it for hours.

[SKETCH PLEASE OPEN ME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7oaV.png)

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document for computer browser */
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
 background-color: #F4F7FA;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 1024px;
 min-height: 768;
}
#wraptable{display: table; width:100%; height:100%;}
#wraprow{display: table-row;}
#wrapcell-left{display: table-cell; width:250px; background-color:#2F323E; overflow:hidden;}
#wrapcell-right{display: table-cell;vertical-align:top;}
.table{display:table; width:100%; height:100%}
.tablerow{display: table-row;}/* global, multiple uses, do not touch */
.tablecell{display:table-cell}

/* Total part of left starts here */
#wraplogo {
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #262A34;
 margin:10px;
    text-align: center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#wraplogo img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
.leftnav-item {
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 25px;
}
.leftnav-item p {
 padding-left: 25px;
 font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
 color: #7E87A3;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:18px;
 margin-bottom:15px;
}
.leftnav-item li {
 width:100%;
 height: 50px;
}
.leftnav-item li:hover {
 background-color:#262A34;
}
.leftnav-bar {display: table; width:100%; height:100%}
.leftnav-item-cell-left {
 display:table-cell;
 height: auto;
 width: 7px;
}
.leftnav-item-cell-middle {
 display: table-cell;
 width:50px;
 text-align:right;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
.leftnav-item-cell-right {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align:middle;
 padding-left: 10px;
 color:#fff;
 font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.leftnav-item-icon {
 width:25px;
}

/* selected item appears different */
.leftnav-item-li-selected {
 background-color:#262A34;
}
.leftnav-item-cell-left-selected {
 display:table-cell;
 height: auto;
 width: 7px;
 /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#53b621+0,34a26a+100 */
 background: rgb(83,182,33); /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(83,182,33,1) 0%, rgba(52,162,106,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(83,182,33,1) 0%,rgba(52,162,106,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(83,182,33,1) 0%,rgba(52,162,106,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#53b621', endColorstr='#34a26a',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

/* ----------------------- Total part of right starts here ----------------------- */
#topbar {
 height: 100px;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align:middle;
 background-color:#fff;
}
#wrapmain {
 display:table-cell;
 overflow:auto;
}
div.scrollbox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Webportaal</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="wraptable">
<div id="wraprow">
<div id="wrapcell-left">
 <div id="wraplogo">
    <img src="img/webportaallogo.png" alt="sitelogo">
    </div>
    <div>
     <div class="leftnav-item">
         <p>Title</p>
            <ul>
             <li>
                 <div class="leftnav-bar">
                        <div class="leftnav-item-cell-left"></div>
                        <div class="leftnav-item-cell-middle"><img src="img/icon-home.png" class="leftnav-item-icon" alt="home-icon" longdesc="img/icon-home.png"></div>
                        <div class="leftnav-item-cell-right">test</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
             <li class="leftnav-item-li-selected">
                 <div class="leftnav-bar">
                        <div class="leftnav-item-cell-left-selected"></div>
                        <div class="leftnav-item-cell-middle"><img src="img/icon-home.png" class="leftnav-item-icon" alt="home-icon" longdesc="img/icon-home.png"></div>
                        <div class="leftnav-item-cell-right">test</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- wrapcell-left stop -->

<div id="wrapcell-right">
 <div class="table" style="table-layout:fixed;">
     <div class="tablerow">
         <div id="topbar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tablerow">
         <div id="wrapmain">
             <div class="scrollbox">
              PING
             </div><!-- stop scroll box --> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- wrapcell-right stop -->

</div><!-- stop wraprow -->
</div><!-- stop wraptable -->
    
</div><!-- stop wrapper -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

cells element can be set to a fixed width*(`table-layout`)* but will grow taller when needed.

You may give a look at the flex model (it can be inbricated and justify-content + align-items will let you deal like if it was cells to align the contents , example below:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
}
#left {
  width:250px;
  background:#333;
}
#left,#right {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
}
#right {flex:1;}
#logo, header {
  height:100px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
header {
  background:gray;
}
nav, main {
  flex:1;
  overflow:auto;
}
nav a {
  display:block;
  border-left:20px solid transparent;
  padding:0.5em;
  color:white
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x80&text=LOGO-fixed"/>
    </div>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>demo
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="right">
  <header> header fixed</header>
  <main> main to scroll if needed
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>demo</main>
</div>
```